# How to launch lightbox clicking on icon ?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I have this icon:

```
<a href="#" class="image-search08">
  <i class="fa fa-search-plus image-search-icon"></i>
</a>
```

How can i launch lightbox and open this : <`img src="img/09.png" data-lightbox="09" class="image-frame" />` clicking on `i` icon?

Comment: just google `jquery lightbox`. you can find many different plugins and choose whichever suits you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Lightbox2, try this:

```
<a href="img/09.png" class="image-search08" data-lightbox="09">
<i class="fa fa-search-plus image-search-icon"></i>
</a>
```